# A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'ValueListenable<int>' in a const constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a Valuenotifier and its shows this error

```
class ScreenHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenHome({super.key});

  static ValueNotifier<int> selectedIndexNotifier = ValueNotifier(0);

  // ignore: unused_field
  final _pages = const [
    ScreenTransation(),
    ScreenCatagaries(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: MMBottomNavigation(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: selectedIndexNotifier,
            builder: (BuildContext context, int updatedIndex, _) {
              return _pages[updatedIndex];
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

```
class MMBottomNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
  const MMBottomNavigation({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: ScreenHome.selectedIndexNotifier,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx, int updatedIndex, Widget? _) {
        return BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedItemColor: Colors.purple,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
            currentIndex: updatedIndex,
            onTap: (newIndex) {
              ScreenHome.selectedIndexNotifier.value = newIndex;
            },
            items: const[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Transation',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.category),
                label: 'Categories',
              ),
            ]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type
> 'ValueListenable' in a const constructor. Try using a subtype, or
> removing the keyword 'const'.

tried to remove all the const from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert ScreenHome to statefull and try this

```
class ScreenHome extends StatelessWidget {
const ScreenHome({super.key});

  int updatedIndex = 0;

// ignore: unused_field
  final _pages = const [
    ScreenTransation(),
    ScreenCatagaries(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: MMBottomNavigation(updatedIndex: updatedIndex,onTap:(i){
          setState(() {
            updatedIndex = i;
          });
        }),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: _pages[updatedIndex],
        ));
  }
}
```

and then

```
class MMBottomNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
  const MMBottomNavigation({super.key,required this.onTap,required this.updatedIndex});
Function(int) onTap;
int updatedIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.purple,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
        currentIndex: updatedIndex,
        onTap: (newIndex) {
          onTap.call(newIndex);
        },
        items: const[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Transation',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            label: 'Categories',
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you tried to remove all the const from the code yet you still get an error saying that you use const?

Make sure you remove const from the follow sections:

1. In your `ScreenHome`:

   ```
   final _pages = const [
    ScreenTransation(),
    ScreenCatagaries(),
   ];  //remove const

   return const Scaffold() //remove const
   ```
2. In your `MMBottomNavigation`:

   ```
   items: const [ 
         BottomNavigationBarItem(), 
         BottomNavigationBarItem(), ] //remove const
   ```

Comment: that didn't help. I removed Both Const. Yet no changes.

Comment: hmm i dont know. Can i see your notifier code? maybe its a const in there